# "Good" Gothik/Fraktur/Blackletter font for math typesetting

Tags: fonts

I need to typeset a document and I am already running out of letters, which is why I want to use `\mathfrak`, `\mathcal` etc to typeset a new range of symbols. The problem is that some of these don't support lowercase letters. Another problem is that `\mathfrak{k}` does not really look like any letter from the regular fonts. Some other letters also look bad.

This is why I am looking for a good font to typeset these letters in. I am using `PdfLaTeX`, however that should not be a problem. I have installed fonts several times already.

One good font I came across was the mathematica Gothik font (the two at the bottom):
[image]
I think it looks pretty readable and every letter can be understood easily. However, this is obviously a commercial font and I cannot simply "get it on the internet".

Another good candiate is [UnifrakturMaguntia](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/UnifrakturMaguntia). However, this font is too "squiggly". I want a font that is more easily readable.

This is why I am asking this question too look for an alternative. I honestly don't know if this is really on-topic here, but I don't known where to ask otherwise either.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [mathalpha](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha) package and, in particular, its baker's dozen of math fraktur font offerings? They are listed on pages 5 and 6 of the package's user guide.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I did. That is also how I discovered the Mathematica font. The problem with the package is that most of these fonts don't seem to support lowercase letters...

Comment: Or at least - if I try to use the lowercase letters I get the wrong characters

Comment: Do you face any restrictions on the use of text font faces for the main document? E.g., must it be Times Roman or Palatino, say?

Comment: @Mico There are no real restrictions; but I would like to keep all other fonts the way they are by default. The new font I am looking for has no restrictions except for the ones I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Which letters/symbols are you missing?

You can try out different fonts with this very basic setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\frakequation}{x^{55}+1 \ne(x^5)^{11}+1-k}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpgoth}{OT1}{pgoth}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathesstixfrak}{U}{esstixfrak}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathboondoxfrak}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtxfrak}{U}{tx-frak}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\matheulerfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}


\begin{document}

\section*{amsfonts}
$\mathfrak{\frakequation}$

\section*{pgoth}
$\mathpgoth{\frakequation}$

\section*{esstixfrak}
$\mathesstixfrak{\frakequation}$

\section*{boondox-frak}
$\mathboondoxfrak{\frakequation}$

\section*{pxtx-frak \emph{1=g}}
$\mathtxfrak{\frakequation}$

\section*{euler-frak}
$\matheulerfrak{\frakequation}$

\end{document}
```

[image: frakmath with k]